# How to create a table in python SQL using another table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

For a programming assignment I have a SQL database with many records of mouse trajectories.
A exercise is to determine the reaction time of a person, by using the timestamp of the first recorded (x,y) coordinates, as it only records the trajectory if the mouse's moving. 
I want the reaction time for every trial of every user.

This is my code:

```
query_reaction_1='''
CREATE TABLE anew_table AS
SELECT t, user, trial 
FROM paths
WHERE t>0
LIMIT 1
'''
pd.read_sql_query(query_reaction_1,db_conn)
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.
Can anyone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why the GROUP BY? (when no aggregate functions are involved.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using sqlite3, if that's what you meant

Comment: Does sqlite really support SELECT TOP? I'd guess they have LIMIT instead.

Comment: Note that TOP/LIMIT/etc without ORDER BY returns a random row.

Comment: @jarlh I thought the groupby was neccesary :/

Comment: No need to GROUP BY here. You can remove it.

Comment: @jarlh now I used this code:

Comment: query_reaction_1='''
CREATE TABLE anew_table AS
    SELECT t, user, trial 
    FROM paths
    WHERE t>0
    LIMIT 1
'''
pd.read_sql_query(query_reaction_1,db_conn)

Comment: @jarlh It now gives 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.read_sql` expects a **select** statement, because it leaves the cursor in a fetchable state. But `CREATE` is a Data Definition Language statement and nothing can be fetched after that. You should use:

```
query_reaction_1='''
SELECT t, user, trial 
FROM paths
WHERE t>0
LIMIT 1
'''
pd.read_sql_query(query_reaction_1,db_conn)
```